# Hangouts Chat bot to post timed message

Tags: chatbot, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I can see from [this](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages/create), that a bot can send a message in chat, and if supplied a thread ID that does not exist, will start a new thread and post there. I am wondering if there is a way, given the current REST API or any other compatible with Hangouts, to send a message to a room at a given time of day, rather than when the bot is called or interacted with.

I am working in NodeJS, deploying my project in the GCP.

My apologies for the ambiguity of my question, I am trying to wrap my mind around the GCP environment.

Answer (score 0):

In the [bots documentation](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/bots-apps-script#events) there are described the three ways in which a bot can send a message to a room. Those are:

- Every time the bot is mentioned.
- When the bot enters a room for the first time.
- When the bot is taken out of the room.

Unfortunately, none of them is a daily message at a given time. If you still have questions, please ask them freely.

Answer (score 0):

We have a working bot (NodeJS based) which sends messages freely. Just use this endpoint https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages/create .

Your bot must be invited to the particular space/room for this. You can create threads as well with new and subsequent messages.

We also have bots written in Google Apps Script and there it is also possible.